# MATLAB: How do I make 10 2D matrices into a single3D matrix using a for loop?

Tags: matlab

I have ten 2D matrices in the form

```
matrix_Q1 = [Q1_inner(:,1) Q1_outer(:,2) Q1_inner(:,1) Q1_outer(:,2)];
```

This is my current for loop, which is incorrect

```
n = 1; 
for X_num = matrix_Q1 : matrix_Q10; 
    X_new(:,:,n) = X_num; 
    n = n+1; 
end
```

I know how to create a 3D matrix with the `x(:,:,1)` syntax, but how do I do this in loop format?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself? Thisis not a code-writing or tutoring service. Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Comment: Could you change the way they're saved in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to create a 3D matrix with it? Perhaps you could just use a cell array for that instead [(see here details on cells)](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com), where you can then use X_new{i} or X_new{i,j} to store each 2D matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that all ten of your 2D matrices are different names doesn't make it ideal for using a loop, unless you use the `eval` function, which I normally don't like using but in this case is necessary.

I would do this:

```
sz = size(matrix_Q1);

X_new = zeros(sz(1),sz(2),10);

for n = 1:10
    X_new(:,:,n) = eval(['matrix_Q',num2str(n)]);
end
```